# Python class calling other method

Tags: python, class, methods

I don't understand why this code doesn't work:

```
import numpy as np 

class Normalizer:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x 
    def mean(self):
        return np.sum(self.x)/np.size(self.x)
    def mean_zero(self):
        return self.x - self.x.mean()
    def new_calc(self):
        return self.x.mean_zero()

    a = np.random.randint(150,200,(5,8))

    heights = Normalizer(a)


    print(a)
    print(heights.mean()) 
    print(heights.mean_zero())
    print(heights.mean_zero().mean())
    print(heights.new_calc())
```

It executes `heghts.mean_zero()` correctly but in the method `def new_calc(self)` it doesn't execute it. It would be great if someone could explain that to me. Thanks!

Comment: mean_zero is class method. You can't call it with your class's variable.

Comment: Use `self.mean_zero()` instead of `self.x.mean_zero()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what `x` from the `__init__` is but it is very likely that you actually want to call `mean_zero` in `new_calc` in the context of `self` variable (the same object):

```
def new_calc(self):
        return self.mean_zero()
```

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand why this code doesn't work:

if you run the following code it will throw an error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'mean_zero'
```

- locate the problem, the only place where `mean_zero` has been called is `new_calc` method. So, first step done.
- analyze, if you look at `Normalize` class it has one attribute `x` which is of the type `numpy.ndarray`. If you carefully read the error message it says that `ndarray` type doesn't have the attribute `mean_zero`. On the other hand you have `mean_zero` method defined in your class and that is the one you should call.

These two steps leads to conclusion that the problem is in `new_calc` method:

```
def new_calc(self):
    return self.mean_zero() #(wrong)return self.x.mean_zero()
```

Answer (score 0):

Insted of self.x.mean_zero() write self.mean_zero()

```
import numpy as np 

class Normalizer:
   def __init__(self,x):
       self.x = x 
   def mean(self):
       return np.sum(self.x)/np.size(self.x)
   def mean_zero(self):
       return self.x - self.mean()
   def new_calc(self):
       return self.mean_zero()

a = np.random.randint(150,200,(5,8))

heights = Normalizer(a)


print(a)
print(heights.mean()) 
print(heights.mean_zero())
print(heights.mean_zero().mean())
print(heights.new_calc())
```

Answer (score 0):

You're initializing Normalizer with 'a', which is the output of np.random.randint, which returns a numpy.ndarray object.

In the new_calc method you are attempting to call the mean_zero method of the ndarray object, but ndarray has no such method. mean_zero *is* a method on Normalizer, but self.x is not of type Normalizer.

I'm not sure what this code `new_calc` is supposed to do. If you can make that clearer, I may be able to provide more assistance.

Comment: new_calc was just a simplification to debug what I am actually trying to accomplish. The actual code will look like this:  def variance(self):
        return (np.sum((self.x.mean_zero()**2)))/ np.size(self.x)

Answer (score 0):

**The culprit:**

```
def new_calc(self):
        return self.x.mean_zero()
```

**The reason:**

`self.x` is an attribute of the `Normalizer` class. So if `heights` is an instance of the `Normalizer` class, then `heights.x` is the `self.x`.

**The answer:**

```
def new_calc(self):
        return self.mean_zero()
```

**The justification:**

> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'mean_zero'

`ndarray` has no such method. `mean_zero` is a method of Normalizer